# Column is not being added to table Mysql using Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-migrations, django-mysql

The following diagram is from my database
[Database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAuc0.png)

I have the following model that represents that schema:

```
class Finalproduct (models.Model):

    idfinalproduct = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    idproduct = models.ForeignKey('Product',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    idtaste= models.ForeignKey('Taste', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    idpresentation = models.ForeignKey('Presentation', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    idcategory = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("idproduct","idtaste","idpresentation","idcategory"),)
```

The cantidad field is not being added in my database table finalproduct. The following is the result of the migration in MySql:
[Mysql, table generated with model shown above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFhD4.png)

I have tried deleting my database, migrations, and the problem is never solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your integer field has to have a default value so try:

```
cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: No, everything seems to be ok. I tried to add the column in the initial001.py, but for some reason it tries to remove the column

Comment: Try to delete the files from migrations folders and only leave __init__.py there